# Site won't load CSS or images without trailing / after URL with Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I've used routing in Codeigniter to get nice clean URLs to my pages. I also have modified the htaccess file to remove the index.php from the URL.

It's all working great except for 1 issue - When I go to a URL it won't load the CSS or Images unless the trailing / is added to the URL.

For example:

mysite.com/blah
Does NOT work

mysite.com/blah/
DOES work

Probaby something in the .htaccess file? Here is my file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|user_photos|favicon|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas? Natrually I want users to be able to access the page even if they don't add the trailing /

Comment: Are you using relative or absolute paths in your includes, i.e. `src="css/filename.css` or `src="/css/filname.css"`?

Comment: My paths look like this: href="css/structure.css" or href="../css/structure.css"

Comment: Did you try changing them to absolute? Do you have the possibility to do that? Did you check Firebug's `Network` tab to see what files are actually request in the scenarios where the CSS's do not load?

Comment: Doesn't work when changing to absolute, the CSS doesn't load on any page.

Comment: I think it's becuase it's treating mysite.com/blah/ as it's own directory, and mysite.com/blah as in the root directory, so it's looking for the CSS in the wrong location (1 directory too high). But I don't know to stop it doing that and treat mysite.com/blah as it's own directory.

Comment: what is the actual location of the css? Is it perhaps `/subdirectory/css/filename.css`?

Comment: No it's not in a subdirectory like that. Just css/filename.css. The whole site is in a subdirectory though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<?php echo base_url();?>` in front of your css URL

**example:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/css/main.css" />
```

As for the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|includes|theme|media|robots\.txt|fonts)
```